# SPWeb being closed when getting list by powershell. What's wrong?

Tags: 2010, powershell, dispose

When I run this little piece of powershell code:

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://localhost
$l = $w.List["some list"]
```

I get *Unexpected* error message to my Sharepoint ULS log

> Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object. .../long message here/...

I don't think this should happen. Is this a bug or do I do something wrong?

---

On the other hand, to make it even more weird. When I wil continue in code above and write this:

```
$w.Dispose()
$w.Title # or any other property
```

I **don't** get that error message. I would expect I **will** get it. What is wrong with disposing in powershell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use of objects, such as `SPWeb` or `SPSite`, in PowerShell requires a proper memory management. Get commands dispose of these objects immediately after the pipeline finishes, but by using SPAssignment, you can assign the list of objects to a variable and dispose of the objects after they are no longer needed. Here is an example of usage of `SPAssignment` object, you can assign SPWeb to a variable and dispose of when they are needed to free up memory. See below:

```
$spAssigment = Start-SPAssignment
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://localhost -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
$l = $spWeb.List["some list"]     
$spWeb.Title # or any other property
Stop-SPAssignment $spAssignment
```

Comment: This is it! Now it work exactly how I would expect. In both cases. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I would like to link to the article I found later, after I read this answer, and which clarifies the use of Start/Stop-Assignment cmdlet and go deep of whats going there when you use it when you didn't.
http://www.codefornuts.com/2010/12/dissecting-sharepoint-powershell.html

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that you are using a regular PowerShell session, probably with the SharePoint snapp-in loaded. And not the 'SharePoint Management Shell'.

With a regular powershell session each command is executed with-in its own thread. And disposable objects, like `SPWeb`, are automatically disposed on the end of a thread. Thus what could happen is that the Garbage Collector is quick and disposes your `SPWeb` before you execute the next statement.

Disposing does not clear or destroy an object, it just gives an object a chance to close connections, clean up things the GC won't clean up, etc. Most properties will still be available (like `Title`) but actions that require a database connection, like `$w.list["listName"]`, will error out.

**SharePoint Management Shell**

The SP Management Shell is just a regular powershell session with this tiny bit of script executed when it loads:

```
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1)  {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = “ReuseThread”}
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Set-location $home
```

Notice the setting on `ThreadOptions`. With the SP Management Shell you get a sligtly different powershell (in an ugly console). One that reuses the same thread for succesive commands, and thus a PowerShell that won't dispose objects 'behind your back'.

See [this blog](http://blog.claudiobrotto.com/2011/sharepoint-management-shell-vs-standard-powershell-console/) for more information.

Load `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1` , instead of just adding the SnapIn

**Tip**
Use the `PowerShell ISE`, which has ThreadReuse on as default. And it is a nice tool for writing and testing scripts.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll give it a try. (your guess in the begining of your answer is right ;) )

Comment: Unfortunately the Sharepoint Management Shell behaves exactly the same :(  
Did you tried it? Did it work for you in Shp Mngmt Shell?

Comment: As I already wrote, this is not the solution for my problem, but thanks for mentioning the config script, it is important to set `ReuseThread` option when I try to use Start-Assignment cmdlet.

Comment: I did not try this, and I didn't know (remember?) about SPAssingment. It is stated on MSDN: "It is important to note that every site collection returned by the Get-SPWeb cmdlet is automatically disposed of at the end of the pipeline. To store the results of Get-SPWeb in a local variable, the Start-SPAssignment and Stop-SPAssignment cmdlets must be used to avoid memory leaks." on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that this is on MSDN. I should have look there first. Thanks.

Comment: Look at MSDN and ask questions here! So we all can learn (as I did about SPAssingment!)

Comment: :) Ok, I will. It is always nice to hear I helped somebody to learn something (even indirectly) ;)